# function get_template_part() problem wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I created website in WordPress on local serwer
I cut my website into several php files
On subpages I put the same code as on the main page,only changing the content
After clicking on the menu, the main page redirects me to the subpage and this error is displayed

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_template_part() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\web\contact.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\web\contact.php on line 2

Main page

```
 <?php 
   defined('ABSPATH') || exit ;
   get_template_part('head');
   get_header();
   get_template_part('slider');
   get_template_part('content-index');
   get_footer();
?>
```

Subpage

```
<?php 
  get_template_part('head');
  get_header();
  get_template_part('slider');
  get_template_part('content-contact');
  get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: You must call `get_header` first to set up WP so that the WP function (such as `get_template_part` ) can work.

Comment: @FluffyKitten but the main page works without get_header at the top

Comment: Hmmm, I think we need to know more info about your setup in that case, because I don't know how that's working! Are you using a child theme? If so, what's the parent theme? If not, what files have you created for your theme and what is your "main page" called (e.g. index.php?).

Comment: I didn't used to a child theme
The first thing what was I created be the whole theme and then uploaded it to wordpress. Yes, my home page is called "index.php". I created content-index, footer, header,nav, slider and subpage contact. All files have a php extension and they are in one file. The main page works, there are errors only on subpages. I added the contact file at the top such a code: if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit( 'Direct script access denied.' );
} and only the inscription was displayed on the page  'Direct script access denied.'

Comment: Have you created the subpages as templates? Index.php is a WP file so that might be why that's working, but contact.php isn't so that problem could be to do with that.

Comment: How could I advertise it? Change contact.php to contact.html and paste concatenated with code from all php files?

Comment: You need to create template file, and then In WP you create a page and select this file as the template for that page. Take a look at the link in my answer, it might cover template files and how to go about creating one, or if not then one if the pages in Google link. But basically it sounds like that’s what the problem is.